# Pointwise array average ignoring NaN

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NumPy: calculate averages with NaNs removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480694/numpy-calculate-averages-with-nans-removed)

I have several identically-shaped numpy arrays. I want to take their pointwise average with a small twist: a `np.nan` value should be ignored in the averaging. In other words, `average(np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([5,np.nan,7]), np.array([np.nan, 4, 2])` should equal `np.array([3,3,4])`.

Of course, I can do that by iterating through the elements within each numpy array, but I was hoping to avoid it. Is there a better way to implement this function?

(Python 3, but I doubt it matters.)

Comment: What you want has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480694/numpy-calculate-averages-with-nans-removed

Comment: @HerrKaputt Sorry, it sure has... I somehow convinced myself that nobody would have been trying to do this, and so I didn't do a careful search for existing questions :(

Comment: No need to apologize! In fact, I don't think hayden's answer (using nanmean) was mentioned in that other link...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.stat`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.stats.html)'s [`nanmean`](http://www.scipy.org/doc/api_docs/SciPy.stats.stats.html#nanmean):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import nanmean
s = np.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [5.0, np.nan, 7.0], [np.nan, 4.0, 2.0]])

In [4]: nanmean(s)
Out[4]: array([ 3.,  3.,  4.])
```

*@Dougal points out in the comments that the [`bottleneck`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck) package, which has  significantly faster implementations of several numpy/scipy functions, includes an `nanmean`.*

Comment: Note that [the bottleneck package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Bottleneck) has `bottleneck.nanmean`, which runs 10-30 times faster in their tests than does `scipy.stats.nanmean`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also convert the array to a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html) (masking all the NaNs with [fix_invalid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.fix_invalid.html)) and perform your operations there:

```
new_array = np.ma.fix_invalid(my_array)
print np.mean(new_array)
```

If it's just for the average, then the suggested `nanmean` by @hayden is about 4x faster. But if you want to do other operations on the array, it's a better bet to use masked arrays instead.