# Mean ignoring NaNs along columns in a NumPy array without using numpy.nanmean

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I have a numpy array like the following:

```
x = array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
           [  4.,   5.,   6.],
           [ nan,   8.,   9.]])
```

and I want to calculate the mean of each column. If I use `np.mean(x, axis=0)`, then I get `nan` as the mean of the first column, and using `x[~np.isnan(x)]` to filter out `nan` values flattens the array into a 1D array.

I'm required to use an older version of numpy, so I can't use [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html)

Edit: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44781504/mean-ignoring-nans-along-columns-in-a-numpy-array-without-using-numpy-nanmean/44781826#comment76544127_44781504) explains why this isn't a duplicate of the question posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy: calculate averages with NaNs removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480694/numpy-calculate-averages-with-nans-removed)

Comment: @StefanoNardo Good find. The answer posts to the linked Q&A there are basically suggesting using `numpy.ma.masked_array`, which I haven't found to be efficient or using `nanmean` in some form, which OP can't use. Given the cirumstances, IMHO using a regular boolean array for masking would be the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be using `boolean-indexing` -

```
def nanmean_cols(x):
    mask = ~np.isnan(x)
    x_masked = np.where(mask, x, 0)
    return x_masked.sum(0)/mask.sum(0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [114]: x
Out[114]: 
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,   6.],
       [ nan,   8.,   9.]])

In [115]: np.nanmean(x,axis=0)
Out[115]: array([ 2.5,  5. ,  6. ])

In [117]: nanmean_cols(x)
Out[117]: array([ 2.5,  5. ,  6. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another approach that doesn't use boolean indexing:

```py
means = []
# Iterate over each column in x
for col in x.T:
    filtered_vals = col[~np.isnan(col)]
    avg = np.mean(filtered_vals)
    means.append(avg)
```

One line version:

```py
means = [np.mean(col[~np.isnan(col)]) for col in x.T]
```