# Picking specific columns and averaging them with some of the values being nan

Tags: python, pandas, average, nan

I have a pandas dataframe & want to calculate the average of some certain columns. But, there are some nan values & my lambda function is ignoring the rows with a missing value in any column. What to do? Here is my code.

```
avgGDP = fdata.apply(lambda x: np.average(x[rows]), axis=1)
```

Comment: Please use pandas built-in function mean: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html . It allows you to decide on what to do with nan values

Comment: Use `np.nanmean` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35832403/2641825)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy: calculate averages with NaNs removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480694/numpy-calculate-averages-with-nans-removed)