# Perform numpy operation with None/NaN in array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any way to make this work? Where the array I'm working on consist of `None`, which means to ignore that value in the processing. For example, I would like to normalize this array:

```py
output = np.array([[1,2,None,4,5],[None,7,8,9,10]])
mu = np.mean(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
sd = np.std(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
normalized_output = (output - mu)/sd
```

Expected outcome:

```
array([[-1.5666989 , -1.21854359, None, -0.52223297, -0.17407766],
       [ None,  0.52223297,  0.87038828,  1.21854359,  1.5666989 ]])
```

**Edit**: As suggested, it is better to use NaN instead of None. How to get this to work with NaN:

```py
output = np.array([[1,2,np.NAN,4,5],[np.NAN,7,8,9,10]])
mu = np.mean(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
sd = np.std(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
normalized_output = (output - mu)/sd
print(normalized_output)
# array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan],
#        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]])
```

Comment: If you have None in your vector, this is a very bad sign: it means the values in the array are of type `object` and so that all related computations are not optimized. Consider using NaN values that are native ones.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I didnt know None is bad for vector. I can use `where` to change it to NaN. Updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: If you want to keep your values integers, use a masked array instead of NaN. I regard NaN as the result of a bad computation (0/0 for example), while a masked value indicates the absence of the value: two different things. NaN is often used for both, but that can lead to confusion.

Comment: NaNs are also taken into account when calculating, for example, a mean value. There are special `nanmean` functions, but here, I think a masked array is more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy: calculate averages with NaNs removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480694/numpy-calculate-averages-with-nans-removed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.nanstd` and `np.nanmean` function instead of `np.std` and `np.mean`

```
output = np.array([[1,2,np.nan,4,5],[np.nan,7,8,9,10]])
mu = np.nanmean(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
sd = np.nanstd(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
normalized_output = (output - mu)/sd
```

you will get output like this

```
array([[-1.54619807, -1.22068269,         nan, -0.56965192, -0.24413654],
      [        nan,  0.40689423,  0.73240961,  1.057925  ,  1.38344038]])
```

It is different from your desired output because `np.nanstd` ignore Nan values present in array so you have 8 elements instead of 10.

Comment: Note that this changes the `dtype` of `output` from `int64` to `float64`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do calculation that skip over certain values by using numpy [masked arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/maskedarray.generic.html).

A function already exists to create a masked array that masks `NaN` values: [`ma.masked_invalid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_invalid.html#numpy.ma.masked_invalid).

It can be used like so:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma


output = ma.masked_invalid([[1,2,np.NAN,4,5],[np.NAN,7,8,9,10]])

mu = np.mean(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
sd = np.std(output, axis=(0,1), keepdims=True)
normalized_output = (output - mu)/sd
print(normalized_output)
```

Output (`--` represents an invalid value):

```
[[-1.5461980716652028 -1.2206826881567392 -- -0.5696519211398116
  -0.24413653763134782]
 [-- 0.40689422938557973 0.7324096128940435 1.0579249964025073
  1.3834403799109711]]
```